# Understanding SSL in Apache HttpClient (Java)

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Here there is an example for custom SSL:
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java

```
/**
 * This example demonstrates how to create secure connections with a custom SSL
 * context.
 */
public class ClientCustomSSL {

public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(new File("my.keystore"), "nopassword".toCharArray(),
                    new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build();
    // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslcontext,
            new String[] { "TLSv1" },
            null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .build();
    try {

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://httpbin.org/");

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        try {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
}
```

Why we need that? I've tested an HttpClient request without any SSL thing on it and I'm getting the correct response from HTTPS urls without errors.
**What is the problem if I don't add any SSLContext?

And if it's important to make it more secure, what is this line?:**

```
.loadTrustMaterial(new File("my.keystore"), "nopassword".toCharArray(),
```

it seems we need some file and also some password?

Comment: The example uses a keystore, which means it is doing client authentication. Evidently either your server didn't ask for a client certificate or didn't mind when you didn't send one because you hadn't configured a keystore.

Comment: @EJP: the code is using a file _named_ keystore, and apparently in a keystore format (because it is read as such without throwing an exception), but it uses the contents as trust material, i.e. as a truststore, to authenticate the server. For Apache httpclient to do client auth, you call (one of the overloads of) `SSLContextBuilder.loadKeyMaterial`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify (a factory using) a context, Java (JSSE) uses a default context containing the default truststore, which defaults to the file `JRE/lib/security/cacerts` (or `jssecacerts` if present) unless overridden with system properties; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CustomizingStores . Depending on whether you are using an Oracle-was-Sun Java package, an IBM or Apple package or Android system, or OpenJDK, this default truststore usually contains more or less the same set of public CAs as most OSes and browsers, like <strike>Verisign</strike> <strike>Symantec</strike> Digicert and GoDaddy and LetsEncrypt/Identrust. Whether you consider the default cacerts 'secure' is a choice for you to make; if not you can either change the contents of the default file, or have your code use a different file and to do the latter yes you must specify the filename of the keystore file and its password.

That example uses a custom store because it is an example of custom SSL. If it used the defaults, it would be an example of default SSL not an example of custom SSL. For many actual applications using the defaults is fine.

Aside: specifying *only* `TLSv1` (meaning 1.0) for protocol is way out of date, and *is* likely to be considered insecure or at least borderline. It hasn't actually been broken outright like SSLv3 (and long ago SSLv2), because BEAST proved tamer than feared, but TLSv1.1 and 1.2 are now widely implemented and used, and 1.3 hopefully not too far away, so using 1.0 is widely considered substandard and for one example applicable to many people TLSv1.0 for payment-card transactions is prohibited outright as of last weekend.

Comment: Before accepting the answer let me see if I understand it: So we need an SSLContext only if we need to recognize some CA not included in the default truststore file from Java right?

Comment: and in that case why is a keystore file added instead of a trustore file? and what is that password?

Comment: Yes. That file _is_ a truststore, but is in keystore _format_; Java uses the same formats (and the same `KeyStore` class) to contain either 'key+cert-for-me' called a PrivateKeyEntry or 'anchor-cert-for-others' (where most anchors are CAs) called a TrustedCertEntry or any combination; list the file with `keytool -list` to see which you have. The password is the password (if any) for the file; the commonly used keystore formats (JKS, JCEKS, BKS, PKCS12) all require passwords, although Java _allows_ a keystore to have no password (e.g. Windows-MY, some PKCS11 devices).

Comment: PS: the (initial) password for the default `cacerts` is `changeit`, which is (AFAICT only) documented near the bottom of the `keytool` page. But since this is the default you don't normally need to specify it.